# Calendar only year an month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have create a table with calender in Power BI using this code:

> Calendario = CALENDAR(FIRSTDATE(PP[Calendar year/month]),LASTDATE(PP[Calendar year/month]))

In my calendar I have only months and I use this code I create a table with every day between the first and the last date.
Is it possible eliminite the date that I don't use? I would like to mantain only 1/1/21 1/2/2021 ect.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

In long, a proper date table in Power BI needs to contain a full year's worth of dates to function properly and support things like time intelligence functions. Even if your data has only sales on a single day e.g. 06/06/23, you need 365 days in your calendar table. In the scheme of things, this is a tiny amount of data and not a performance or storage concern.

Also, don't forget to mark your new table as a date table and turn off auto time intelligence.